SQL Date within range to give result
I'm looking to get a code that'll help me get a result from a date range based on a date.
Table A D.O.B
1994-04-12
1996-12-06
2009-11-22

Table B DATE RANGE COLUMN



Start
cut off




1990-01-01
1999-12-31


2000-01-01
2009-12-31



SO... i want to get date from table A and match it with table B if it is between Start and cut off ?
I've tried multiple different ways and they don't work.

Can you show us what you have tried and what your expected results are

"I've tried multiple different ways and they don't work." So neither BETWEEN or >=/<= worked..?

What is your desired output for that sample data?

Create a Date Dimension, and add your Start and Cutoff Columns, and from what I see, possibly a "Decade" column. Then just join your Table A to the DateDimension to get your decade value. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

You can join the 2 tables using BETWEEN
SELECT * 
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB  B on A.DOB BETWEEN B.Start and B.Cutoff

fiddle



DOB
Start
cutoff




1994-04-12
1990-01-01
1999-12-31


1996-12-06
1990-01-01
1999-12-31


2009-11-22
2000-01-01
2009-12-31



